# CRUD operation sample or book

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new WPF and MVM pattern. I looking for a book or site which discusses and teaches WPF in reference to doing CRUD operation using DataGrid and other basic controls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too but you can start by reading the caliburn project documentation (http://www.caliburnproject.org/). The documentation is so so clear that after reading it, you can start working. There are a lot of samples on the site too

The caliburn project is a MVVM framework design to work with wpf, silverlight and WP7+

It's open source and a lot of peopleo are using it (it was use in nhproof development http://nhprof.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This control [WPFCrudControl](https://github.com/GenericCodes/WPFCrudControl) may fit with your needs.

A generic WPF CrudControl implemented based on the MVVM pattern. It gives a huge productivity boost for straightforward CRUD operations (Add, Edit, Delete, Validate, Listing with sorting, paging and searching). The control abstracts both the UI and business logic, so it requires relatively minimal coding effort, while keeping it possible to customize its behavior.